# How to config github oauth2 passport.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, passport-github2

I use github oauth2 passport.js. After first time logged in my app auto logged in. I think this problem this `prompt` config. But it is not worked.
Here my code:

```
router.get('/auth/github', 
passport.authenticate('github',{ 
    scope: [ 'user:email' ], 
    prompt: 'select_account' 
}));
```

Comment: Please, add more details,  (like the authentication function or passport configuration code) about your problem

Comment: only here problem have. In register work good.